# copy folder from one to another in aws s3 in php

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy a folder to another in aws s3 as below

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(
    array(
      'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'testbucket',
        'secret' => BUCKET_SECRET //Global constant
      ),
      'version' => BUCKET_VERSION, //Global constant
      'region'  => BUCKET_REGION  //Global constant
    )
  );
$sourceBucket = 'testbucket';
$sourceKeyname = 'admin/collections/Athena'; // Object key
$targetBucket = 'testbucket';
$targetKeyname = 'admin/collections/Athena-New';

// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
));
```

It is throwing error as

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with
>   message 'Error executing "CopyObject" on
>   "https://testbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/admin/collections/Athena-New";
>   AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT
>   https://testbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/admin/collections/Athena-New`
>   resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
>   `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not
>   exist.admin/collections/Athena`NoSuchKey`The specified key does not
>   exist.admin/collections/Athena29EA131A5AD9CB836OjDNLgbdLPLMd0t7MuNi4JH6AU5pKfRmhCcWigGAaTuRlqoX8X5aMicWTui56rTH1BLRpJJtmc='

I can't figure out why it is making wrong bucket url like

> https://testbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/admin/collections/Athena-New

While right aws bucket url is

> https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/admin/collections/Athena-New

Why it is appending the bucket name to before s3 in url?

In simple words, I wanted to copy the content of

> https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/admin/collections/Athena

to

> https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/admin/collections/Athena-New

Comment: Using the bucket name as a subdomain does not necessarily make the URL invalid.

Comment: actually it is appending it here anyway. I thought that might make it a wrong key to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to "copy a folder" in Amazon S3 because folders do not actually exist.

Instead, the **full path** of an object is stored in the object's `Key` (filename).

So, an object might be called:

```
admin/collections/Athena/foo.txt
```

If you wish to copy all objects from one "folder" to another "folder", then you will need to:

- Obtain a listing of the bucket for the given `Prefix` (effectively, full path to the folder)
- Loop through each object returned, and **copy the objects one-at-a-time** to the new name (which effectively puts it in a new folder)

So, it would copy `admin/collections/Athena/foo.txt` to `admin/collections/Athena-New/foo.txt`

Comment: Is it possible to rename a folders?

Comment: No. Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. They "appear" in the interface, but they are merely for display purposes, taken from the full path (Key) of objects. To "rename a directory" you actually need to copy all the files with that path to new objects with a different path, then delete the original objects. The thing to understand is that **the name (Key) of an object includes the full path**. So, moving an object actually involves creating a new object with the new name.